# Insertion in the database using Hibernate Java

Tags: hibernate, insert

I am trying to insert the values from textfields in the database using hibernate and it doesn't work.
For example I want to insert into the Product table, where I have the following columns:
idproduct, idprovider, idcategory, name, quantity.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Product product = new Product();
    int idProduct = Integer.parseInt(IdProductTextField.getText());
    product.setIdproduct(idProduct);
    session.save(product);
    tx.commit();
```

This is the only column that is inserted, because in the set method I have a int parameter.

But all the other columns don't work. And here is the problem:

All the other set methods for the other columns that I want to insert in the Product table have as parameter a Class variable. For example:

If I want to insert the idprovider, the set method for this is

```
public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}
```

And I really don't know how to insert the idprovider, using this method.

I have little time and I would appreciate if somebody could help me as quick as possible.

I attach here the Product.java and the Provider.java

```
package sakila.entity;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Product  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private int idproduct;
 private Istoricprod istoricprod;
 private Provider provider;
 private Category category;
 private String name;
 private Integer quantity;
 private String unitmas;
 private Set comdetals = new HashSet(0);
 private Set stocs = new HashSet(0);
 private Set bondetals = new HashSet(0);

public Product() {
}


public Product(int idproduct) {
    this.idproduct = idproduct;
}
public Product(int idproduct, Istoricprod istoricprod, Provider provider, Category category, String name, Integer quantity, String unitmas, Set comdetals, Set stocs, Set bondetals) {
   this.idproduct = idproduct;
   this.istoricprod = istoricprod;
   this.provider = provider;
   this.category = category;
   this.name = name;
   this.quantity = quantity;
   this.unitmas = unitmas;
   this.comdetals = comdetals;
   this.stocs = stocs;
   this.bondetals = bondetals;
}

public int getIdproduct() {
    return this.idproduct;
}

public void setIdproduct(int idproduct) {
    this.idproduct = idproduct;
}
public Istoricprod getIstoricprod() {
    return this.istoricprod;
}

public void setIstoricprod(Istoricprod istoricprod) {
    this.istoricprod = istoricprod;
}
public Provider getProvider() {
    return this.furnizor;
}

public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
    this.provider = provider;
}
public Category getCategory() {
    return this.category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getQuantity() {
    return this.quantity;
}

public void setQuantitaty(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
public String getUnitmas() {
    return this.unitmas;
}

public void setUnitmas(String unitmas) {
    this.unitmas = unitmas;
}
public Set getComdetals() {
    return this.comdetals;
}

public void setComdetals(Set comdetals) {
    this.comdetals = comdetals;
}
public Set getStocs() {
    return this.stocs;
}

public void setStocs(Set stocs) {
    this.stocs = stocs;
}
public Set getBondetals() {
    return this.bondetals;
}

public void setBondetals(Set bondetals) {
    this.bondetals = bondetals;
}
```

}

And the Provider.java is

```
package sakila.entity;
```

// Generated Apr 9, 2012 10:19:40 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class Provider  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int idprovider;
 private String denumire;
 private Integer codfiscal;
 private Integer nrfirma;
 private String stradadom;
 private Integer numardom;
 private String orasdom;
 private String judetdom;
 private Integer telefon;
 private Integer codiban;
 private String banca;
 private Set produses = new HashSet(0);
 private Set chitantas = new HashSet(0);
 private Set comandas = new HashSet(0);
 private Set facturas = new HashSet(0);

public Provider() {
}


public Provider(int idprovider) {
    this.idprovider = idprovider;
}
public Provider(int idprovider, String denumire, Integer codfiscal, Integer nrfirma, String stradadom, Integer numardom, String orasdom, String judetdom, Integer telefon, Integer codiban, String banca, Set produses, Set chitantas, Set comandas, Set facturas) {
   this.idprovider = idprovider;
   this.denumire = denumire;
   this.codfiscal = codfiscal;
   this.nrfirma = nrfirma;
   this.stradadom = stradadom;
   this.numardom = numardom;
   this.orasdom = orasdom;
   this.judetdom = judetdom;
   this.telefon = telefon;
   this.codiban = codiban;
   this.banca = banca;
   this.produses = produses;
   this.chitantas = chitantas;
   this.comandas = comandas;
   this.facturas = facturas;
}

public int getIdprovider() {
    return this.idprovider;
}

public void setIdprovider(int idprovider) {
    this.idprovider = idprovider;
}
public String getDenumire() {
    return this.denumire;
}

public void setDenumire(String denumire) {
    this.denumire = denumire;
}
public Integer getCodfiscal() {
    return this.codfiscal;
}

public void setCodfiscal(Integer codfiscal) {
    this.codfiscal = codfiscal;
}
public Integer getNrfirma() {
    return this.nrfirma;
}

public void setNrfirma(Integer nrfirma) {
    this.nrfirma = nrfirma;
}
public String getStradadom() {
    return this.stradadom;
}

public void setStradadom(String stradadom) {
    this.stradadom = stradadom;
}
public Integer getNumardom() {
    return this.numardom;
}

public void setNumardom(Integer numardom) {
    this.numardom = numardom;
}
public String getOrasdom() {
    return this.orasdom;
}

public void setOrasdom(String orasdom) {
    this.orasdom = orasdom;
}
public String getJudetdom() {
    return this.judetdom;
}

public void setJudetdom(String judetdom) {
    this.judetdom = judetdom;
}
public Integer getTelefon() {
    return this.telefon;
}

public void setTelefon(Integer telefon) {
    this.telefon = telefon;
}
public Integer getCodiban() {
    return this.codiban;
}

public void setCodiban(Integer codiban) {
    this.codiban = codiban;
}
public String getBanca() {
    return this.banca;
}

public void setBanca(String banca) {
    this.banca = banca;
}
public Set getProduses() {
    return this.produses;
}

public void setProduses(Set produses) {
    this.produses = produses;
}
public Set getChitantas() {
    return this.chitantas;
}

public void setChitantas(Set chitantas) {
    this.chitantas = chitantas;
}
public Set getComandas() {
    return this.comandas;
}

public void setComandas(Set comandas) {
    this.comandas = comandas;
}
public Set getFacturas() {
    return this.facturas;
}

public void setFacturas(Set facturas) {
    this.facturas = facturas;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take the provider for example. If you have the provider id of an existing provider, you can do

- load the provider with the id first
- set the provider into the product
- save the product

example (not complete)

```
Provider provider = session.load(provider, idProvider);
product.setProvider(provider);
session.save(product);
```

If you do not want to load the provider first (perhaps superfluous database access), then you can do

```
Provider provider = new Provider(idProvider);
product.setProvider(provider);
session.save(product);
```

In this case make sure in the mapping file `cascade` is set to `none`; if not also a new provider would be created (if you also want a new provider being created, set `cascade=all`).

A third possibility is, in product you do not put a provider object but only the provider id and map it as simple integer. (You even can put both the separate id and the provider object, but that is a bit tricky and generally not recommended.)

Comment: You should never assign a fake, new Provider to an entity you save. This will be a mess because a saved entity will be attached to a transient one. Session.load() doesn't do any database access. And, as you said, if you change the cascade type, it could delete all the data of the provider.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, you have a many-to-one association between you Product and its Provider. When you insert a product, you want it to link it to an existing provider. So you get the provider which has the given ID, and attach this provider to the product:

```
Provider provider = (Provider) session.load(Provider.class, idOfTheProvider);
product.setProvider(provider);
session.save(product);
```

The same goes for the othe associations.